# Cannot convert string column to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column called '2016 Salary ($)' that contains employee pay from a table Salary Paid as a number, to the DataFrame income. I want to strip that number by removing '$'and ','.

But when I am doing this I get the error saying:

> 'Could not convert string to float'

I try to follow the hint, but it is not working:

```
income['2016 Salary ($)']= income['SalaryPaid'].str.strip('$').astype(float)
income['2016 Salary ($)'].apply(lambda X:X['Salary Paid'])
income
```

Comment: Please show part of the data, change the code to code block using CTRL+K and the error you got.

Comment: There is column called name - jack, Salary =$204,546,289.35 Year= 2016. I want ato add a column that just get a number from salary and placed in the income['2016 Salary ($)'] = 204546289.35. 
When i try to write the code it says cannot convert string to float

Comment: `income['2016 Salary ($)']= income['SalaryPaid'].str.strip('$,').astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

**Data** :

```
dic = {'Name':['John','Peter'],'SalaryPaid':['$204,546,289.35','$500,231,289.35'],'Year':['2008','2009']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1

    Name    SalaryPaid      Year
0   John    $204,546,289.35 2008
1   Peter   $500,231,289.35 2009
```

**Code**:

```
df1['SalaryPaid'] = df1['SalaryPaid'].str.replace(',', '')
# If you want the result as a string : 
df1['2016 Salary ($)']= df1['SalaryPaid'].str.strip('$')
# if you want the result as float : 
#df1['2016 Salary ($)']= df1['SalaryPaid'].str.strip('$').astype(float) 


df1
```

**Result**:

```
    Name    SalaryPaid  Year    2016 Salary ($)
0   John    $204546289.35   2008    204546289.35
1   Peter   $500231289.35   2009    500231289.35
```

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df.SalaryPaid.replace(['\$',','],'',regex=True),errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 2):

Add [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) first:

```
income['2016 Salary ($)']= income['SalaryPaid'].str.replace(',', '')
                                               .str.strip('$')
                                               .astype(float)
```

Or better solution if create `DataFrame` from file is use `thousands` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
income = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',')

income['2016 Salary ($)']= income['SalaryPaid'].str.strip('$').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

i have created a dummy dataframe as per your requirement and have performed the same operation as you had mentioned above and it worked fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AA','BB'])
df['AA'] = ['$12,20','$13,30']
df['BB'] = ['X','Y']
print(df)
```

Output ----->
    AA  BB
0   $12,20  X
1   $13,30  Y

```
df['AA'] = df['AA'].str.replace('$','').str.replace(',','').astype(float)
print(df)
```

Output ----->
AA  BB
0   1220.0  X
1   1330.0  Y

According to me the error is in second line of your code where you are trying to apply lambda, instead of "income['2016 Salary ($)'].apply(lambda X:X['Salary Paid'])" it should be "income['2016 Salary ($)'].apply(lambda X:X['SalaryPaid'])". I think there is a typo error with column named SalaryPaid.

Answer (score 0):

can also do:

```
def convert(x):
    return float(x.replace('$','').replace(',',''))

income['2016 Salary ($)'] = income['Salary Paid'].apply(convert)
```

or

```
def convert(x):
    return float(''.join(re.findall('[\d+\.]',x)))
```